# Textview with clickable links in Sony small apps

Tags: android, textview, sony

I have a textview in my sony small app with following attributes set

```
android:autoLink="web|email|phone"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

But when I run the app, and click on any phone number in the textview, i get an exception say

```
E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from  outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:886)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:880)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
```

Since my app is a Sony Small App, I don't have any activity, it is SmallApplication. Is there a way I can fix this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: as your error message said..just add  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK when you start an activity..

Comment: yes, but I don't have a control on code where this startActivity is called, it's from within android's URLSpan onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag is needed to start activity from Small App.
You can see startActivity() is called at line #62 of URLSpan class in the error message.

One possible solution is to modify URLSpan class to call startActivity() with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and use modified URLSpan for TextView.

For example,

1. Create new customized URLSpan class by extending URLSpan class and overriding onClick() method to call startActivity() with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
2. Create SpannableString for auto link text and set customized URLSpan by SpannableString.setSpan() method.
3. Set above SpannableString to TextView